# MySQL: Selecting duplicates among many fields

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to select emails that are duplicates:

```
SELECT email
                FROM contacts
                WHERE active = 1
                GROUP BY email
                HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1)
```

In the case above, if two users have the same email, that query will show them. However, there is another email field named `email2`, what can I do so that I compare the count among many email fields? (So, for example, if a user has email equal to email2 of another user, they will be considered duplicates)

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think I am in the same page with you here. Why counting email and email2 in order to find duplicates? You could use "count(email)/count(email2) AS Duplicate"in your project. You will have 1 for duplicate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tmp.email FROM (
    SELECT email as email FROM contacts WHERE active = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT email2 as email FROM contacts WHERE email != email2 AND active = 1
) as tmp
GROUP by tmp.email
HAVING COUNT(tmp.email) > 1
```

P.S : my syntax could be wrong, but the idea should be something like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT email
FROM contacts
WHERE (email = email2) AND (active = 1)
```

if I'm interpreting you correctly. Or do you mean that some user records may have "user@example.com" in the `email` field in one record, and the same address in the `email2` field in another record? that'd be

```
SELECT primary.email, primary.id, secondary.id
FROM contacts AS primary
INNER JOIN contacts AS secondary ON (primary.email = secondary.email2)
```